# Facebook, C# and Console Application

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk, console-application

I am able to connect to facebook using the C# SDK via my console application but the Facebook Access Key expires every couple of hours and I have to be logged in to my facebook account for it to work at all.

I am using the following code to enumerate photo albums :

```
var usertoken = FBImageChecker.Properties.Settings.Default.FBUserAccessKey;
var fbclient = new FacebookClient(usertoken);
dynamic albums = fbclient.Get("me/albums");
```

Am I correct in thinking I should be using oAuth now?  if so, does anyone have an example which could work in my case?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Have you tried to use OAuth?  There are hundreds of examples of how to use OAuth within a C# application including a SDK that Microsoft wrote to support Facebook among other services.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally managed to get this working using oauth, unfortunately facebooks documentation is not exactly clear and although there are many examples online as pointed out by @ramhound a lot of them apply to older authentication models so it was a case of trial and error.

Comment: Can you let us know what approach you followed to make it work? A link to that site which helped you, would be enough.